# onDestroy method not exist in receiver. What is alternative?

Tags: android

I am using a `Service` and I dynamically register a receiver like

```
private BroadcastReceiver yourCallReceiver;
 yourCallReceiver = new CallReceiver();

        // Registers the receiver so that your service will listen for broadcasts
        registerReceiver(yourCallReceiver, theCallFilter);
```

and unregister like

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Do not forget to unregister the receiver!!!
        unregisterReceiver(yourCallReceiver);
    }
```

but i am having problems that i need to shutdown some work whene i unregister receiver, but receiver does not have `onDestroy` method. How can i do this? how can i stop some third party work when unregister receiver in service? is this even possible?

Comment: why don't you call a user-defined clean-up method on the `yourCallReceiver` as soon as the `unregisterReceiver` is called?

Comment: but from service i can not call method in receiver? or can I? Can you give me an example. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a method called `onDestroy` (or whatever you want to call it) in your custom `CallReceiver` class as follows:

```
public void onDestroy(){
  //Write your clean-up code here
}
```

In your Service's `onDestroy`, call the `onDestroy` on your receiver object:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Do not forget to unregister the receiver!!!
    unregisterReceiver(yourCallReceiver);
    yourCallReceiver.onDestroy();
}
```